# jinja2 gloable set doesnt work

Tags: variables, set, global, jinja2

I am writing a template of `jinja`. In the html file, I wrote:

```
{% set tmpx, tmpy = 0 %}

{% for greeting in greetings %}
    {% if greeting.author %}

        {% tmpx = greeting.data_x %}
        {% tmpy = greeting.data_y %}

    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The result is the program cannot find `tmpx`, `tmpy`. So confused about how to use
global set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do too much with jinja. You cant access the value of a variable which you set inside any block like if or for block. You should move all the logic to your controller. Just access the values here :)